# Cannot assign value of type '[Currency]?' to type '[Currency]?.Type'

Tags: json, swift4, decodable

I am trying to decode a struct which has an optional array

```
struct AppInitData:Decodable{

    var ApplicationID:String?
    var Currencies = [Currency]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case ApplicationID = "ApplicationID"
        case Currencies = "Currencies"
    }

    enum DataKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case AppInitData = "Data"
    }

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: DataKeys.self)
        let productValues = try values.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: .AppInitData)

        self.Currencies = try productValues.decodeIfPresent([Currency].self,forKey:.Currencies)

    }
```

**Compilation Error 1:**

> `var Currencies = [Currency]?`  ==> Expected member name or
>   constructor call after type name

**Compilation Error 2:**

> `self.Currencies = try productValues.decodeIfPresent([Currency].self,forKey:.Currencies)` ==>
>   Cannot assign value of type '[Currency]?' to type '[Currency]?.Type'

Not sure what is missing here, Can anybody point out?

Comment: Of course it's wrong! Your declaration is wrong `var Currencies = [Currency]?` should be  `var Currencies: [Currency]?`. Have a look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/variable-declaration)

Comment: FYI, property name should start with lowercase letter. Use `camelCase`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare it like this

```
   var Currencies :[Currency]?
```